# Is it possible in Room to ignore a field on a basic update

Tags: android, gson, android-room

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
class Foo(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thing1")
    val thing1: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thing2")
    val thing2: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thing3")
    val thing3: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thing4")
    val thing4: String
) {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "local")
    var local: String? = null

}
```

Where local is information that is not stored on the server, only local to the phone.

Currently when I pull information from the server GSON auto fills in my values, but since "local" does not come from the server it is not populate in that object.

Is there a way that when I call update I can have Room skip the update for the "local" column without writing a custom update to insert into all other columns except "local"?  The pain point is that I could have many columns and each new column I add, I would have to add that to the custom insert statement.

I have also thought of a one-to-one mapping from the server entity to a new "local" entity, however now I have to deal with the pain of a join statement everywhere I get my entity since I need the local information.

I was hoping that I could do something like this:

```
@Entity
class Foo(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thing1")
    val instructions: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thing2")
    val instructions: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thing3")
    val instructions: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thing4")
    val instructions: String
) {

    @Ignore
    var local: String? = null

}
```

Using the @Ignore annotation, to try and ignore the local string on a generic update.  Then provide a custom update statement to just save the local info

```
@Query("UPDATE foo SET local = :newLocal WHERE foo.id = :id")
fun updateLocal(id: Long, newLocal: String)
```

However ROOM seems to be smart enough to check that I used @Ignore on the local property and it will not compile with that update statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: You said: _Currently when I pull information from the server GSON auto fills in my values, but since "local" does not come from the server it is not populated in that object._ Can you share how you do this?

Comment: Would `onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE` work? upon update, the "local" field will conflict and will be ignored

Comment: @jackz314 No it does not work. onConflict will check if primary keys are the same or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Partial Updates got added to Room in `2.2.0`

In Dao you do the following:

```
// Here you specify the target entity
@Update(entity = Foo::class)
fun update(partialFoo: PartialFoo)
```

And along your entity `Foo` create a `PartialFoo` containing the primary key and the fields you want to update.

```
@Entity 
class PartialFoo {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thing1")
    val instructions: String,
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834309/1724097

Comment: Can you add a Java version, please?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is **NO**. Room doesn't have conditional insertion or partial insertion.

You have to come up with your insertion logic. The best one I guess is call both database and server for data and just update your server response' `local` value with your database response' `local` value.

If you are comfortable with *Rx*, then you can do something like this

```
localDb.getFoo("id")
    .zipWith(
        remoteServer.getFoo("id"),
        BiFunction<Foo, Foo, Foo> { localFoo, remoteFoo -> 
            remoteFoo.local = localFoo.local
            remoteFoo
        }
    )
```

Another possible way is to write custom `@Query` that you insert all the values except local, but it's not feasible if you have lots of fields.