# Room is there any way to not insert/update value if null

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I've recentyly started using Room and I would like to know if when inserting or updating an Entitiy there's any way to check if the value is null, and in that case, do not insert it /update it.

What I want to do is something like

```
@Entity
data class Person{
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val name:String
    val surname:String
 }
```

Would it be possible in a simple way to perform an @Update operation for those fields which are not null? and those which are null keep them as tey are?

For example in an update perhaps I might have informed the id and the name, but in another update I might have informed the id and the surname. So what I want is to merge the information, but if possible without having to make a select query to check the values stored.

I've read the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789325/update-some-specific-field-of-an-entity-in-android-room/59834309#59834309), but my doubt then it would be, is it possible to define an @Entity, with all the fields defined as the one I mentioned before and then have other entities to just update some fields, something like:

```
 @Entity(tableName = "person")
data class PersonUpdateSurname{
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val name:String
 }


@Entity(tableName = "person")
data class PersonUpdateSurname{
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val surname:String
 }
```

Is there a way to tell Room which is the original table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell Room which is the original table structure?

This question is not clear. Maybe there is some misunderstanding you have.

Try to follow next schema:

1. There should be only one `Person`-related data class annotated with Room-annotations - @Entity, @PrimaryKey and so on. In your case it is `Person` class.
2. All the rest mentioned auxiliary classes should be just POJO (plain data classes), since they are not being persisted. In your case - `PersonName` and `PersoneSurname` (with the fields you described but without Room's annotations).
3. In DAO use `entity`-parameter in @Update:

```
@Update(entity = Person::class)
fun updateName(personName: PersonName)

@Update(entity = Person::class)
fun updateSurname(personeSurname: PersonSurname)
```

In your Repository call method what you need. If you want to update only name - you use  method `updateName()` and instance of `PersonName` class as a parameter, for only surname's update - method `updateSurname()` and instance of class `PersonSurname`.