# How to update database set new value upon to old value by android room?

Tags: android, android-room

I want to update my database by android room. But I can not find a way to do some thing like this:

```
UPDATE persondata SET age=age+1 where id=123;
```

So does room have this ability, and how can I do it? custom my Dao class?

Comment: Check if this answer helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834309/963038

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this example of mine and modify yours accordingly.

`@Query("UPDATE order_item SET Quantity = Quantity + 1 WHERE id = (:cart_id)")            fun increaseCartQuantity(cart_id: Int)`

Answer (score 0):

You can update the object directly using the update annotation.

```
/**
 * Update an object from the database.
 *
 * @param obj the object to be updated
 */
@Update
fun update(obj: T): Int
```